# Is there a way to quickly decide which variables to use for model fitting and selection?

Tags: machine-learning, model, regression

I loaded a dataset with 156 variables for a project. The goal is to figure out a model to predict a test data set. I am confused about where to start with. Normally I would start with the basic linear regression model, but with 156 columns/variables, how should one start with a model building? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The question here is pretty open ended.

1. You need to confirm whether you are solving for regression or classification.
2. You need to go through some descriptive statistics of your data set to find out the type of values you have in the dataset. Are there outliers, missing values, columns whose values are in billions as against columns who values are in small fractions.
3. If you have categorical data, what type of categories do you have. What is the frequency count of the categorical values.
4. Accordingly you clean the data (if required)
5. Post this you may want to understand the correlation(via pearsons or chi-square depending on the data types of the variables you have) among these 156 variables and see how correlated they are.
6. You may then choose to get rid of certain variables after looking at the correlation or by performing a PCA (which helps to retain high variance among the dataset) and bringing the dataset variables down to fewer dimensions.
7. You may then look at fitting regression models or classification models(depending on your need) to have a simpler model at first and then adjusting things as you look at improving your accuracy (or minimizing the loss)

Comment: After cleaning the data as mentioned here, you can also try the "leave-one-out" technique where the model is first made with all predictor variables and a fit statistic is calculated. You would then iteratively re-run the regression, each time leaving out one of the predictor variables to determine the effect on the fit statistic. This can be automated, and can often help to weed out some of the less helpful predictor variables.